# How to uninstall OpenResty from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

How to uninstall OpenResty from Ubuntu 16.04?

I am trying to uninstall OpenResty from my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I'm not sure how OpenResty was installed. My server is running apache2